# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. with Web API

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-web-api

I am getting this exception **"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."** in my server when trying to access one of Web API methods. But the other methods are working fine. And the API is working fine with all methods in the Dev Environment(Local).

And Most important thing is it is not consistent...some times I am able to get the result from the API...sometimes doesn't.

And my log file says the following error

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.get_IsEOF()
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
```

[image]

This is the error I am getting when I hit the Method from the client. Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed...It is due to some unreleased resources. Used the "Using" Clause for the database accessing code. Now it is fixed.